# How to set an Image on UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Set navigationController an image with size 750 × 90 Image Size

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

after setting image to navigation controller its not completly drawing image on UINavigationController.

How to set an image on `UINavigationController` Bar.

Answer (score 3):

try this

> use the method of resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode: and set the resizingMode to **UIImageResizingModeStretch**, else the image would still Same in the navigation bar.

```
UIImage *currentImgae =  [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]
                                     resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:currentImgae forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**Swift**

```
let currentImgae = UIImage(named: "bg.png")!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0), resizingMode: .Stretch)
self.navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(currentImgae!, forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```